# express, coffeescript, Title not working

Tags: express, coffeescript

I have the coffee file, I am following peepcode screencast 069.

```
 routes = (app) ->
 app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
 res.render "#{__dirname}/views/login",
   title: 'Login'
   stylesheet: 'Login'

 module.exports = routes
```

this is my layout.jade file

```
  doctype 5
  html
   head
      title= title
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
       block content
```

No when I hit the webpage on ,y local server, it does show, but the title is not showing as Login. What am I missing?

Comment: what does your view look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about half the things you mentioned, but looking at the CS: your functions aren't indented properly. Shouldn't it look like this:

```
routes = (app) ->
  app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
    res.render "#{__dirname}/views/login",
      title: 'Login'
      stylesheet: 'Login'

module.exports = routes
```